# Tired of Visual Studio themes

Tags: visual-studio, colors

It is really so relaxing to use dark or blue background for editor so i interested in Visual Studio color themes.

I found alot of them which was looking nice at first sight but i realized all of them has ugly problems when i use them. Color settings wasn't tuned well in all scenario so there were a lot of time that i can not read my codes.

I love Ruby theme so is there any well designed settings for ruby theme or any theme ?

Answer (score 5):

[All the Visual Studio themes you can shake a stick at.](http://studiostyles.info/schemes)

Comment: The page already experienced by me badly. Many themes looking nice at a glance but not for all scenarious.

Comment: I personally find the WekeRoad Inc style the best all around, though I will say I made a couple of edits to suit my tastes better (like background color of matched parenthesis).

Comment: @Julie - A horrible theme. I prefer dark blue or black backgrounds

Comment: @qstarin - I agree! My favorite as well...so nice to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I love the wombat color scheme in Vim and so I looked around and found this: [My attempt at converting the VIM Wombat theme to support Visual Studio](http://mohundro.com/blog/2008/01/11/my-attempt-at-converting-the-vim-wombat-theme-to-support-visual-studio/)

Works fine for me in VS2008.